# vscode jest extension doesn't work properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs

I'm working with **VSCode** and installed the **extension**: "**Jest**" for better jest-testing-enviroment.

In the extension's instruction I saw we get a ***nice intellisense support*** for Jest's commands.

#### The Problem:

1. I dont get "Jest" icon on the bottom bar, which means the ext doesnt work properly.
2. I still dont get the intellisense support for jest's commands

#### My Question:

Did anyone had this issue and find the way to configure it properly ?

Comment: Did you tried with [this](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest#troubleshooting)? `If one of these applies, and you're not seeing the "Jest" in the bottom bar, run the command Open Developer Tools and see if something has crashed, we'd love to know what that is, and ideally a project we can run against.`

Comment: @robi I saw this, but wasnt sure where exactly do I run this command ?

Im running it on windows 10, and by just typing it into the terminal it dosnt work. I also tried to run in inside ***vscode command palette and it didnt work

Comment: If you're still passionate about getting vscode-jest running, let's restart this conversation on the repo. We need a few more contributors to get involved with the project. https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solution:

Once I understood my folder structure was the reason for the extension not to work properly, I started using VSCode's ***Workspaces***.

### Explanation:

When using ***Workspaces*** you can have multiple projects in one folder.
Each will be count as a root project.
The Workspace allows you to have multiple root projects in the same folder (which actually solved my problem).

When working with Jest without setting a `jest.config.js` file, you get your `rootDir` to its default (which is the folder where the `package.json` is in).

#### P.S.

From what I experienced till now, ***vscode-jest extension*** is not so stable and still has some bugs. So in my case, I decided to disable it for the meanwhile.

Comment: Yes Workspaces work very well, I have my web src in a sub-directory, plugin doesn't recognize my jest files. Either I could add an empty jest.config to the subdir, or add this subdir as a Workspace (File -> Add folder to Workspace)

Answer (score 13):

Highly recommend using the [jest runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firsttris.vscode-jest-runner) extension instead.

Demo:

[image: ]]

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: For me, it worked out-of-the-box contrary to `jest` extension

Answer (score 6):

On a fresh install of the extension, it **didn't work properly for me right out of the box** either. Running `npm run test`  on the WSL2 terminal worked, but the extension didn't.

My **folder structure** was

```
root
__tests__
         __testThis__
                     featureA.js    <-- jest tests
         __andThis__
                    feature1.js     <--
                    feature2.js     <--
testThis.js
andThis.js
package.json
```

and my test script was initially `"test": "jest --watchAll --maxWorkers=1",`
on my package.json.

But it **finally worked after doing the ff.**:

### (1) Jest icon not appearing in bottom status bar

- **Specify jest.rootPath in .vscode/settings.json** . Documentation elaborates more on this [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest#troubleshooting).
- I set mine as "" (empty) since I used testMatch to find my tests.

  ```
  "jest.rootPath": "",
  ```

### (2) jest command not found

- make sure **jest and jest-cli are installed in the shell used by the jest extension**
- I had been running tests using WSL2 with no issues (without the extension), but encountered "jest command not found" with the extension.
- After installing jest and jest-cli on Git Bash, this was no longer a problem.

### (3) Extension runs for a split second, then "watch-tests" ended unexpectedly

- Instead of using the Jest extension wizard, I ran `jest --init` at the root of my project to **create a jest.config.js**. This updates the test script to `"test": "jest"` -- I left this as is after.
- **enable testMatch** in the resulting jest.config.js, so jest knows where to look for tests

  ```
  testMatch: [
     "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
     "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
  ],
  ```

### (4) Tests finally run, but they run repeatedly until CPU usage goes --> ~90%

- **turn jest autoRun off in .vscode/settings.json**

  ```
  "jest.autoRun": "off",
  ```
- click thru the jest extension's **side bar icon (the Erlenmeyer flask) to run tests only as needed**

Even then, not everything in the extension works perfectly (e.g. the debugger still doesn't work for me), but **am able to run single tests (or all tests at once) using the extension**.

Hope this helps somehow!

Comment: Setting root  path worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I just placed a `jest.config.js` at the root of my monorepo and the extension picks up. The problem, for me at least, was that it was looking for that file starting at the root path, and never finding it.

Comment: Having a similar setup (monorepo), creating an empty `jest.config.js` at root level was what finally fixed it for me (Jest 29.0.3)

Answer (score 0):

After wasting lot of time  and installing lots of extensions. I found out that we have to install `@types/jest` as dev dependency for intellisense to make our intellisense work in VSCode.

`npm i -d  @types/jest`

[image]

Note: If installing @type/jest doen't work, try restarting VSCode. I have also attached my package.json fo reference, so that you can match if anything else missing for Jest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I run Windows 11 and the Jest extension for VS Code started working on installing `pre-release version 6.1.0`

Then I could see `Jest: Run Related Tests` in the dropdown

[image]