# Cannot find module jest-sequencer-@jest/test-sequencer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug Jest tests in VSCode, but it can't resolve some modules. I set a breakpoint where `jest.run` is called below is the `argv`

```
"--runInBand"
"--no-cache"
"--watchAll=false"
"--config"
"{\"roots\":[\"<rootDir>/src\"],\"collectCoverageFrom\":[\"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\",\"!src/**/*.d.ts\"],\"setupFiles\":[\"/Users/username/projects/project-name/CSharpProjectName/src/ClientApp/node_modules/react-app-polyfill/jsdom.js\"],\"setupFilesAfterEnv\":[],\"testMatch\":[\"<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\",\"<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\"],\"testEnvironment\":\"jsdom\",\"testRunner\":\"/Users/username/projects/project-name/CSharpProjectName/src/ClientApp/node_modules/jest-circus/runner.js\",\"transform\":{\"^.+\\\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$\":\"/Users/username/projects/project-name/CSharpProjectName/src/ClientApp/node_modules/react-scripts/config/jest/babelTransform.js\",\"^.+\\\\.css$\":\"/Users/username/projects/project-name/CSharpProjectName/src/ClientApp/node_modules/react-scripts/config/jest/cssTransform.js\",\"^(?!.*\\\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)\":\"/Users/username/projects/project-name/CSharpProjectName/src/ClientApp/node_modules/react-scripts/config/jest/fileTransform.js\"},\"transformIgnorePatterns\":[\"[/\\\\\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\\\\\].+\\\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$\",\"^.+\\\\.module\\\\.(css|sass|scss)$\"],\"modulePaths\":[],\"moduleNameMapper\":{\"^react-native$\":\"react-native-web\",\"^.+\\\\.module\\\\.(css|sass|scss)$\":\"identity-obj-proxy\"},\"moduleFileExtensions\":[\"web.js\",\"js\",\"web.ts\",\"ts\",\"web.tsx\",\"tsx\",\"json\",\"web.jsx\",\"jsx\",\"node\"],\"watchPlugins\":[\"jest-watch-typeahead/filename\",\"jest-watch-typeahead/testname\"],\"resetMocks\":true,\"rootDir\":\"/Users/username/projects/project-name/CSharpProjectName/src/ClientApp\"}"
"--env"
"/Users/username/projects/project-name/CSharpProjectName/src/ClientApp/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js"
```

My suspicion is that the value for `--env` is what is causing the problem.

For reference, I my config files:

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  testRegex: "(.*)\\.(test|spec)\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
  rootDir: "/Users/username/projects/project-name/CSharpProjectName/src/ClientApp",
  modulePaths: [
    "<rootDir>"
  ],
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom"
};
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/src/ClientApp/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
            "args": ["test", "--runInBand", "--no-cache", "--watchAll=false", "--env=jsdom"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src/ClientApp",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "env": { "CI": "true" },
            "disableOptimisticBPs": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Directory structure:

```
project-name   
└── CSharpProjectName
    ├── .vscode
    │   ├── tasks.json
    │   ├── launch.json    
    │   └── settings.json 
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── src
        ├── ClientApp
        │   ├── jest.config.js
        │   ├── package-lock.json
        │   ├── package.json
        │   ├── public
        │   │   ├── favicon.ico
        │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   └── manifest.json
        │   ├── src
        │   │   ├── App.test.tsx
        │   │   ├── App.tsx
        │   │   ├── components
        │   │   │   ├── Home.tsx
        │   │   │   ├── Layout.tsx
        │   │   │   └── NavMenu.tsx
        │   │   ├── index.tsx
        │   │   ├── react-app-env.d.ts
        │   │   └── registerServiceWorker.ts
        │   └── tsconfig.json
        ├── Program.cs
        ├── Startup.cs
        ├── CSharpProjectName.csproj
        └── appsettings.json
```

And I open VS Code from the `CSharpProjectName` directory.

EDIT:

Tried using `cross-env` as the executable in launch.json. Also did not work:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Cross Env Debug CRA Tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/src/ClientApp/node_modules/.bin/cross-env",
            "args": ["CI=true", "${workspaceRoot}/src/ClientApp/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts", "test", "--env=jsdom"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src/ClientApp",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "disableOptimisticBPs": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66406512/jest-cannot-find-module and it did not help.

Comment: Also looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887321/vscode-jest-extension-doesnt-work-properly when I couldn't get the  VS Code Jest extension to work either. Tried a clean VS Code install. No dice.

Comment: Have read through this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/debugging-tests/

Comment: What is the output when you run it via the command line?

Comment: `$ node_modules/.bin/react-scripts test --runInBand --no-cache --watchAll=false` works

Comment: `node_modules/.bin/cross-env CI=true node_modules/.bin/react-scripts test —env=jsdom` works

Comment: Also fails: ```{
            "name": "Cross Env Debug CRA Tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/src/ClientApp/node_modules/.bin/cross-env",
            "args": ["CI=true", "${workspaceRoot}/src/ClientApp/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts", "test", "--env=jsdom"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src/ClientApp",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "disableOptimisticBPs": true
        }```

Answer (score 22):

Something *eerily* similar started happening to me, today.

I finally discovered that, in VS Code, I had accidentally ticked on "**Breakpoints** --> **Caught Exceptions**" in the "Run and Debug" view at some point. This caused the *appearance* of this error, but one that could be ignored by continuing to run (or by unticking that "Caught Exceptions" option).

Comment: Legend, I had also set both _Caught Exceptions_ and _Uncaught Exceptions_ and then later thought I'd broken jest ‍♂️