# Debugging jest test in VS Code shows "Error: Cannot find module "jest-environment-node"

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I have troubles with debugging my jest tests. Maybe I introduce my setup first:

```
root-dir
  test
    sample.spec.ts
  jest.config.js
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
```

The contents of `sample.spec.ts`:

```
describe('Sample', () => {
  it.concurrent('App', async () => {
    expect(true).toEqual(true); // here the breakpoint is set
});
```

});

So nothing fancy to be debugged here. I installed the [Jest Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firsttris.vscode-jest-runner) extension in VS Code.

However, when I "click" the "Debug" button, right above the `it`, the debugger starts, but shows an exception:

```
Exception has occurred: Error: Cannot find module 'jest-environment-<path-to-my-root-dir>\node_modules\jest-environment-node\build\index.js/package.json' from '<path-to-my-root-dir>'e
```

What is the problem there? In the `node_modules` directory, the `jest-environment-node` is there. The path form the exception is not correct, hence it can't find the `package.json`. But this one I can't influence!

I appreciate your help!

Kind regards to all of you!

Answer (score 6):

I've found the solution to this problem... which isn't a problem at all. It is also answered here: [Cannot find module jest-sequencer-@jest/test-sequencer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71705702/3950150)!

So... never ever tick `Caught Exceptions` and `Uncaught Exceptions` in VS Code: [image: exceptions]

Without those two ticks, `jest` works out of the box.

Comment: Ohhh you just saved me after tearing my hair out for a few hours

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this answer.  I was getting really desperate.